# Clustering of multidimensional trajectories

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, cluster-analysis

I have a big dataset with multiple flight trajectories. These trajectories have all a unique id to identify them. They are in a classical pandas Dataframe. Every sample of a trajectory has multiple features like longitude, latitude, altitude, velocity and many more, like 15 dimensions.

My goal is to find a clustering algorithm that can work with a whole multi dimensional trajectory as its input and it will cluster the trajectories only by their whole trajectories.

It should be an algorithm with a dynamical amount of clusters, so k-mean won't work

I tried clustering them with DBSCAN but the problem is, that one trajectory got different cluster labels for samples inside of it. It was only possible to feed sample per sample into DBSCAN and not a whole trajectory.

I was also thinking of converting a trajectory to a single row, but that would end up with way to many dimensions that would end in the curse of dimensions I guess.

I also heard of distance matrices, but wouldn't they end in multiple dimensions as well so it can't be feeded into DBSCAN?

I would be very thankful for helpful answers!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are purely interested in trajectory clustering then I assume that you could just consider (at least as a starting point) longitude, latitude and altitude. This sounds like quite a generic problem. A search for 'distance between trajectories' quickly yields. e.g. [*A survey of trajectory distance measures and performance evaluation*](https://zheng-kai.com/paper/vldbj_2019.pdf). For R (not what you want, I know) I found https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/trajectories/vignettes/article.pdf. Searching for 'distance between trajectories python' gave several results but nothing that stood out as an out-of-the-box 3D working solution. Following these links perhaps you can get more of a grip on the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! I read a lot of paper about distance measures but I still lack the knowledge, of how I can cluster the results of them. I saw that many people use DBSCAN for Trajectories but can't find a solution how to convert the trajectory data that it can be used as input for DBSCAN.

Comment: I haven't used DBSCAN much myself, but looking e.g. at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html they say "Perform DBSCAN clustering from vector array or distance matrix", so in that implementation you can compute the distance matrix yourself, give it to DBSCAN and it will directly use those values without inferring distances itself.  This is often a distinction offered by clustering methods, where they allow both a feature matrix as input (needing distance calculation) or a pre-computed distance matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I discovered in parallel the library HDBSCAN that is a modification of DBSCAN from sklearn, giving more options. I will go with the distance matrix, trying different distance metrics.